# Fullscreen WebView when landscape?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm trying to build an app with a webview which should go fullscreen when the orientation changes to landscape. I did the way with layout-land and main.xml where I just gave the WebView fill_parent and it was over all the other views. The problem with that was, that the WebView was lagging. I hope there is another way to do it. My WebView loads a URL which is created by a button in relation with what the user put into some spinners. So if the fullscreen webview needs a new activity I need to parse the URL. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your main Activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration config) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    switch(config.orientation) {

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
        break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN); 
            ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

}
```